# Problem github action, build jar with maven and dockerfile

Tags: docker, maven, github-actions

I have problem with build .jar when push to github action
I want to deploy my apps to server with github action, but i think maven build and dockerfile have conflict when create .jar in target folder

My Error:

this error show the jar can't locate in any directory
[This is the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr3zu.png)

```
 > [2/3] COPY target/visual_query_builder-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar visual_query_builder-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:
133
------
134
Dockerfile:4
135
--------------------
136
   2 |     EXPOSE 8888
137
   3 |     WORKDIR /
138
   4 | >>> COPY target/visual_query_builder-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar visual_query_builder-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
139
   5 |     ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/visual_query_builder-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
140
--------------------
141
error: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to walk /tmp/buildkit-mount841757013/target: lstat /tmp/buildkit-mount841757013/target: no such file or directory
142
Error: buildx failed with: error: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to walk /tmp/buildkit-mount841757013/target: lstat /tmp/buildkit-mount841757013/target: no such file or directory
VPS - pull image and run app container
```

My Dockerfile:

What missing in my dockerfile?

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
EXPOSE 8888
WORKDIR /
COPY target/visual_query_builder-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar visual_query_builder-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/visual_query_builder-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

My deploy.yml:

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
        with:
          driver-opts: network=host
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          java-version: '11'
          distribution: 'adopt'
      - name : Cache Dependencies
        id : cache-dependecies
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~/.m2/repository
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-maven
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-maven
      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn clean package
        
      - name: Check Directory
        run: |
          pwd

      - name: Build and push to local registry
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: true
          tags: bi.nti.co.id/vqube/neural_bi_vqube:latest
      -
        name: VPS - pull image and run app container
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: bi.nti.co.id
          username: dev
          port: 8288
          key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
          script: |
            docker pull bi.nti.co.id/vqube/neural_bi_vqube:latest
            docker-compose -f vqube/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Comment: Did you try the docker build locally i.e not on GH actions? Also, are you sure the package version in your pom.xml is `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` ? I wouldn't hardcode the version in the Dockerfile btw, just because the build will fail if you update versions.

Comment: @Karo Karo , I am facing the same problem. did you find solution to this ?